# Excel formula returning 0.125 as answer for all conditions- what am I doing wrong?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements

I'm trying to do some conditional logic in Excel, and my formula keeps giving me 0.125 as my answers even when I know it shouldn't.

This is the code:

```
=IF(AND((H4/G4)<=2,G4<=0.125),0.015625,
IF(AND((H4/G4)>2,G4<=0.125),"FRE",
IF(AND((H4/G4)<=2,AND(0.125<G4,G4<=0.1875)),0.03125,
IF(AND((H4/G4)>2,AND(0.125<G4,G4<=0.1875)),0.03125,
IF(AND((H4/G4)<=2,AND(0.1875<G4,G4<=1)),0.0625,
IF(AND((H4/G4)>2,AND(0.1875<G4,G4<=1)),0.0625,
IF(AND((H4/G4)<=2,G4>1),0.125,
IF(AND((H4/G4)>2,G4>1),0.125,
"ERROR"))))))))
```

An example of the output it should give me is this, however instead of the 0.0625 values that these two should give me, I get 0.125 for everything.

| Column G | Column H | Column I |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.365 | 0.980 | 0.0625 |
| 0.500 | 6.000 | 0.0625 |

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Nothing immediately jumps out as wrong. For your first result, it looks like you're expecting the condition "AND((H4/G4)>2,AND(0.1875<G4,G4<=1)" to return true. Try selecting Formulas > Evaluate Formula to step through the calculation and see if things are behaving as expected.

Comment: I went through the formula using the evaluate formula tool and the problem seems to arise from the fact that excel seems to think 0.365 is not less than 1. I have no idea why it thinks this.

Comment: You must've made a typo since I wrote your formula (translated it to my language) step by step even though you could've written it way shorter, and it works. Did you accidentally have G4<1 by any chance?

Comment: In that case I suspect that the "0.365" in your cell is actually a piece of text and not a number (or some similar issue with formatting that makes the cell look like the number you expect, but the underlying data is different). Try selecting the cell to see if it has a ' at the start. You should also try clearing all formats with `Home` > `Clear` > `Clear Formats`.

Comment: The formula in my code is an exact copy-paste of what I sent here, so I'm not sure where the typo would be. I can keep looking though.

Comment: I tried the clear formats as well, it didn't seem to change anything sadly.

Comment: Do you also get "FALSE" when typing `=G4<1`?

Comment: Yes, =G4<1 returns FALSE even when it shouldn't.

Comment: What happens if you highlight the "G4" in that formula (=G4<1) and press F9? (That will evaluate the cell reference to show you what Excel thinks the cell's value is.)

Comment: Ok... Back to basics we go, is `0.365<1` also false? Because then it'd be language related (even though you should be getting an error when trying to type your formula). If not I'd  say it's what CheChe mentioned about it being text, not a number.

Comment: This is the formula I have in cell G4: 
=MID(LEFT(F4,FIND("X",F4)-1),5,LEN(F4))
It references cell F4 which says this: 
BGCR.500X6.000-120

Comment: That's text, type at the very end *1, like so: `=MID(LEFT(F4,FIND("X",F4)-1),5,LEN(F4))*1`

Comment: =0.365<1 returns as TRUE, so I believe that it is the text vs. number problem. But I thought that would be fixed since I selected the columns and had them formatted as numbers.

Comment: Formatting as numbers doesn't make it a number, see [explanation here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-format-number-text/#:~:text=An%20important%20thing%20to%20remember,number%20will%20appear%20as%200.57.) and the reason why your H4/G4 works is because it's also a calculation (rather than a comparison) forcing it to be read as a number.

Comment: Just fyi, checking whether it's both >2 and <=2, is illogical and you can just check for the secundary condition like `If(G4<0.125, 0.015625,` etc.

Comment: My bad, I meant for the ones you have the same outcome for like with the 0.0625, not when it's separate like with the 0.015625 <> "FRE"

Comment: Yeah I know that for most of them this is illogical, I only wrote it this way because it's based off of some ASTM standards that I'm supposed to follow. But yeah you're right, I could shorten these up a good bit and it wouldn't change anything, so I may as well do that.